# phrase request for "knowing your physician"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm helping a colleague of mine to write an essay on physician-patient relationship and here is the deal:
In the introduction part we want to say that,

> patients' "knowing" of their doctors changes significantly based on
>   their hospitalization history.

by saying "knowing" we actually meant having some background information like certain ways of behavior of their doctors and etc, but the word "knowing" sounded a bit odd to me.
I'm asking for a single-word or maybe a proper phrase or even a jargon in substitution of that weirdly used "knowing".

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a word request so much as proofreading . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Things that you know" would more often be termed **[knowledge](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/knowledge?s=t)**:

> 1. acquaintance with facts, truths, or principles, as from study or investigation; general erudition:
>      *knowledge of many things.*
> 2. familiarity or conversance, as with a particular subject or branch of learning:
>      *A knowledge of accounting was necessary for the job.*
> 3. acquaintance or familiarity gained by sight, experience, or report:
>      *a knowledge of human nature.*

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

Your sentence would then become:

> patients' **knowledge** of their doctors changes significantly based on their hospitalization history.